# Can I name a file .pl and run it as html on server?

Tags: php, html

I want to know if it is possible to name file `.file.pl` and run it as HTML.

I want this to exploit CORS misconfiguration of a website which only checks origin header for `.realwebsite.pl` and we can add anything before the dot but not after `pl`.

Comment: (1) You don't "run" HTML files. (2) What web server? (3) How is PHP involved in this? (4) More of an aside, but what is CORS?

Comment: Although you want to use this to exploit a CORS vulnerability, the question itself is not about security. It's about what a web server will run.

Comment: If you fully control a web site you can make the path part of the URL and (thus the Origin header) anything you want as long as it stays a syntactically correct URL. This includes serving HTML data with a URL ending in `.pl`, `.gif` or whatever. But I agree with schroeder that the fact that this can be done and also how this can be done is not actually a security question.

Comment: You can not exploit a CORS misconfiguration this way. I am assuming you will be serving this from your own domain. The origin header does not include any path, so browsers will not send the names of any files. Therefore, you won't be able to fake the origin by using clever filenames.

Comment: @schroeder The correct answer here is not about server config, it's about how CORS work. That is a security issue and I think this should be reopened.

Comment: @Anders the underlying question is about CORS, but the question as asked is about either file extensions or Perl. I think the entire question needs to be re-thought,

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, however it all depends on how the web server (Nginx, Apache, etc) is set up to serve those files back. For example, it is very much possible to have a web-server that knows nothing about PHP, and therefore if provided a `.php` file, it will simply return it as plain-text, i.e. the MIME type of `text/plain`.

If you have full control of the server, you could probably set it up so it serves files with `.pl` extensions as `text/html`... but then you're not really exploiting any vulnerability.

You can't "run something as HTML", since HTML is not a programming language, it is a markup language, hence "**H**yper**t**ext **M**arkup **L**anguage". It is a syntax that is then parsed by a web browser to display elements on a web page. You can think of HTML to being similar to Markdown, which is just another syntax that is then used by a Markdown parser (like you see on GitHub).

Comment: see this https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: That link just shows you how to remove the file extensions from a webpage using the rewrite engine. 

This means rather than browsing for a file called: `http://example.com/test-data.html`, you can find it by doing `http://example.com/test-data`.

Again this hasn't got much to do with security, rather it's server setup.